# Looking for a prior declaration, introduced by friend declaration

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend

There is a quote from 3.4.1/7:

> When looking for a prior declaration of a class or function introduced
>   by a friend declaration, scopes outside of the innermost enclosing
>   namespace scope are not considered;

Can you get an example to demonstrate this rule?

Comment: The [**Name Lookup**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) section of cppreference has a fairly solid description of this and many other interesting lookup conditions. It is worth the read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. This code works (both classes are in the same namespace):

```
namespace Foo {
  class Bar
  {
  friend class FooBar;
  public:
    Bar() : i(0){}
  private:
    int i;
  };

  class FooBar
  {
    FooBar( Bar & other )
    {
      other.i = 1;
    }
  };
}//namespace Foo
```

And this code fails (the friend class is outside of the `Foo`'s enclosing namespace, thus the lookup fails and you see the the `int Foo::i is private within this context` error):

```
namespace Foo {
  class Bar
  {
  friend class FooBar;
  public:
    Bar() : i(0){}
  private:
    int i;
  };
}//namespace Foo

class FooBar
{
    FooBar( Foo::Bar & other )
    {
        other.i = 1;//Oops :'(
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This rule regulates where the compiler is looking for functions or classes marked as `friend`. It regulates, that the compiler will only check functions or classes in the same namespace as the class which allows `friend` access. It will not check functions or classes in other or outer namespaces.

---

This code will produce an error:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a {
  class Q { int x; friend void foo(Q q); };
}

// function foo is in outer namespace (not in a)
void foo(a::Q q) { std::cout << q.x << std::endl; }
//                              ^^^ ERROR q.x is private

int main() {
    a::Q q;
    foo(q);
}
```

The reason is that the function `foo` is not in the namespace `a`, but in an outer namespace (in this case the global namespace). Thus `foo` does not match the friend declaration in `Q`.

---

This code will work:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a {
  class Q { int x; friend void foo(Q q); };
}

// function foo is in same namespace as Q
namespace a {
  void foo(Q q) { std::cout << q.x << std::endl; }
//                            ^^^ OK access allowed by friend
}

int main() {
    a::Q q;
    a::foo(q);
}
```

This works because the function `foo` is now in the same namespace as `Q`. Thus `foo` matches the friend declaration in `Q`.